# KDE not starting automatically anymore

Tags: kubuntu, kde, autostart

I installed Kubuntu on a new Lenovo laptop on which I want to keep Windows 10 in dual boot.

It was not easy and I had some troubles to be able to start the installation but it worked. I was not able to choose the username during the installation process, instead, I had OEM in the field which was grayed.

I thus made a new user, and then deleted the OEM user because it was starting KDE automatically with this user. And since then, the computer is booting, then I have an underscore character on tty7, and KDS is not starting anymore.

I know I made it the wrong way, and probably broke some init process by doing so, but I think it's not much to fix because I can still start KDE by :

Going to TTY1, logon and then launch the startx command.

Can anyone help me and tell me how I can fix this (or how to be able choose the username during installation process) ? many thanks in advance for your help & advices :-) !

Have a good day ! ^^

Comment: Uhh... You made an OEM install, you were suppose to double click the icon "ready to ship to final user" that appears (appeared?) In the OEM session.

Comment: I just tried again installation process from scratch and no... I have no icon on the desktop after login in with OEM user :-/.
Anyway you pointed my mistake, I will reinstall in normal mode, I probably touched the down arrow by mistake in the grub menu without noticing it the first time... And I was thinking this was due to another protection on the Lenovo... shame on me :o)... and thanks again !!

Comment: Is there any way to force the "ready to ship to final user" action BTW ? Just for my knowledge... :-).